# Groups of even order have an element whose order is 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to prove this question.

Q. If G is a group of even order, prove that it has an element a, such that a$\neq$e satisfying $a^2$=e.

I tried solving it using Principle of mathematical induction. 
So, Let O(G)=2m, where m$\in$ $N$.

We proceed by induction on m.

For m=1,
O(G)=2, $\therefore$ G contains two elements.

G=$\{{e,a}\}$. Now, e has order 1. So, a can not have order 1. $\therefore$ a has order 2. So, it true for m=1.

Now, let it be true for m=k.

Then, we have a group G of order 2k, where $\exists$ an element a$\in$ G, whose order is 2.

We wish to prove it for m=k+1.

Then G has order 2k+2.

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: You're going down very much a wrong path, I'm sorry to say. There's basically no link between groups of size $n$ (or $2n$) and those of size $n+1$ ($2n+2$) because so much of the structure of a group is based on its 'factorization' and there's no commonality between the factorizations of $n$ and $n+1$. You could try and use 'general induction' by factoring $2n$, but what do you do in the cases where $n$ is prime or for groups that don't factor cleanly (since the result is true for all groups, not just abelian ones)?

Comment: Induction isn't a good way to proving all statements, not even all statements of the form 'for all $n$, $P(n)$ holds'. Sometimes the direct proof is just the way to go.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $x\to x^{-1}$ is always an involution on $G$. Can an involution of a set with an even number of elements have precisely one fixed point ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** 
$$x^2=e \Leftrightarrow x = x^{-1}$$

This means that the elements of order $\neq 2$ can be split in disjoint pairs $\{ x, x^{-1} \}$. Since the identity element $e$ is equal with its own inverse.......

Comment: Therefore, there has to be another element of order 2 to complete the pair. I got your point. How can I incorporate this in my proof?

Comment: @user160370, you cannot: the idea of your proof does not work.

Comment: you cannot incorporate this into your proof. You should start a new proof using this idea.

Comment: @user160370 In order to use the inductive step, you need to find a group of order $2m$ inside the group of order $2m+2$. Such a group doesn't exist if $m \geq 3$.